# How Can I Have the Chrome Development Drawer, Network Panel, to autoscroll along with new lines?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, google-chrome-devtools

Up to yesterday, the Network Panel of Chrome's Development Drawer would display the new http requests, and the scrolling handle would stay at the bottom of the scrolling guide. The image linked below points to what I refer to as the scrolling handle (I don't qualify to display images on my posts due to my reputation):

[Screenshot of Chrome Browser with the Development Drawer > Network Panel Opened. A red arrow points to what I refer to as the Panel's scrolling handle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FBbX.jpg)

This video illustrates what I am experiencing. I have updated Chrome, reset the headers of the columns for the information I want to see, and restarted the browser, but I am unable to get the scrolling handle to behave as it did before (i.e., to stay at the bottom of the scrolling guide, and thus display each new line as it is generated): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2f1mpbM-1s&t=22s

How can I get the scrolling handle to stay all the way down, or along the new generated information lines, or autoscrolling to newly generated lines?

Chrome Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)